# Login through google on different websites always asking second approval on phone

Tags: login

When I try to login to different websites (For example: Feedly) which require authentication through google, I am always asked to undergo additional check wherein I approve the request through my android phone. I have also tried checking 'remember me on this computer' option. This is not the case when I try to access any of these websites through my MacBook. How can I make these websites remember my credential when I login through Ubuntu ?

Comment: This is likely a problem on the other end. One possible method that worked in the past: change the user-agent in the browser to the one you use on your macbook.

Comment: Have you got 2FA set up on your Google account?